# Is the alignment of children specifically mentioned anywhere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

Is there a rule that says what humanoid children have as an alignment?

I know that, barring a specific exception, the general rules of alignment would apply. Animals have a specific mention in the text as having an exception (they are always neutral). What I'm looking for is whether children have a specific exception that sets their alignment differently than the general rule does.

In this context, "children" means people up to the pre-teen years, whatever those years are for the different races.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

There is no specific discussion of children's alignment in any PF product I am aware of.

Harming children is used as an example of evil, I believe, but the actual alignment of the children is not.

Source:  Have read most of pathfinder.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not mentioned anywhere. But even pre-teen children have a personality.

They can be well-behaved and listen to their parents (lawful) or ill-manered and do as they please (chaotic).

They can also have tendencies to bully other children and steal their toys (evil) or share their toys with others and protect younger children from bullies (good).

The only case which I would put into the neutral bin without further thought would be a toddler which is not yet able to interact with its environment at all.

So the same alignment rules which apply to adults also apply to children.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie fixed.